# Safari .scrollTop() jQuery Nav Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I’m new to web development and I’m having some troubles.

My project requires for me to have a centred logo image at the top of the page with the navigation bar under it. However, when the user scrolls down, the navigation has to move up and stay fixed, unless the user scrolls back up to the top — in which case, the navigation bar goes back to its original position.

I’ve achieved this with jQuery using the following code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 10) {
    $nav.css('top', 'initial');
    } else {
      $nav.css('top', '0px');
     }
  });
```

It works in all browsers, except for Safari. In Safari, when scrolling down the page, the navigation bar moves to the top but the more that I scroll, the more it slides up, away from view, and eventually disappears from the top.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your current code in it?